# Is there limit of runbook and variable number in an azure automation account?

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am planning to have an `automation account` which will contain `runbooks` and `automation account variables`. The number of runbook and variables will increase in time, automatically.

How many runbook and automation account variable can an azure automation account contain? Is there a limitation for that?

I have checked [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/azure-automation-service-limits.md) but couldn't find anything related to `runbook` and `automation account variable` number.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5635d3af-d336-46b9-8760-1b81a301b507/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-azure-automation-accounts-one-can-create-in-an-azure-subscription?forum=azureautomation) which can answer your question. It mentioned that "**From what the Automation team has explained to me if the limit is not set in the quota doc located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#automation-limits) then the limit does not exist or it is high enough that they have never ran into a customer hitting a limit.** "

The content of the doc is same with what you provided in your question, I think you just need to refer to this document.